# How do I enable video decoding on gpu (ATI) and XBMC?

Tags: hardware, ati, xbmc

I just built an HTPC / homeserver, I used ubuntu 10.04 lucid lynx and combined it with xbmc.

The hardware I'm using is Asus e35m pro (embedded low voltage cpu and HD6310 gpu).

However if I run 1080p video footage, everything starts to stutter. I checked with htop from an ssh connection and noticed one of the cores goes into 100% load.

I was wondering why it does not use the GPU instead ? (I have installed proprietary drivers from ATI). Do I have to change settings ?

Is it XBMC related, ubuntu related or does ATI just not support hardware video decoding on their GPU on linux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure who to point the finger at, but what essentially happened is that NVIDIA provided one API to do this with their cards and ATI provided one for theirs. As you can guess they are not the same, so in order for programs to take advantage of this, they have to be coded to support it.

From what I can find, this is not currently in the stable release of XBMC (Dharma 10.1), but lucky for you is in branch for the next release. Your options at this point are to either wait for the Eden edition, or jump ahead and get a nightly build of XBMC. Obviously the nightly build can be unstable, and you have to accept that as part of the risk if you choose to so.

If you want to go the nightly route, check out [this](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=99154) thread on the XBMC forums that gives you a couple different options and ways to get it installed.

Oh, also apparently if you are willing to go the Windows (ducks just in case somebody gets mad, sorry) route, the zacate seems to work pretty well on that platform also.

Comment: Not going to kill you for that it was my backup plan xD, but thank you for pointing this out :D

Comment: No problem. You may also want to check out openelec, I think I read somewhere on the forums that they have a zacate build out. I run it on one of my systems and it works pretty well.

Comment: I've seen it before, but I was wondering if you can run it ontop of  an OS ? Because my htpc is also my homeserver (apache2, mysql,...)

Comment: No I do not think that is an option for openelec. It is its on distribution. That is one of the drawbacks of it. It is designed to turn XBMC it to an appliance, so it locks down a lot of functionality you normally get with linux. But it makes it super easy to get XBMC running.

Answer (score 1):

I have same hardware and this thread was big help for me. Especially xbmc from lars-opdenkamp repository.

http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=98169

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a fusion based system? For me the following guide was very helpful: http://youresuchageek.blogspot.nl/2012/06/xbmc-install-and-config-howto-for-linux.html

If you just want xbmc in ubuntu (not standalone) install the xbmc-xvba from the wsnipex ppa as mentioned in the guide. (also follow the bit on only enabling xvba, not vaapi and vdpau and the refreshrates). For me (on ubuntu 12.04) compiz didn't like xbmc but if I started xbmc with the following script it worked as expected and with hardware acceleration:

```
#!/bin/bash
metacity --replace &
sleep 2s
xbmc
unity --replace &
exit;
```

It will kill compiz, start xbmc, and start compiz again when you're closing xbmc.